# R: download pdf embedded in a webpage

Tags: r, pdf, rselenium

Trying to find an easier way to grab the table in the pdf embedded in this [page](http://www.dmo.gov.uk/ceLogon.aspx?page=about&rptCode=D10A) or even better, download this pdf into a local drive:

My code is below and results are messy...

PS: none of the buttons at the bottom of the webpage works unless you use IE, and IE with RSelenium... I have created a code to load the page on IE, can successfully click on any of the buttons to either load the excel file (stuck at the step where it pops up a window to ask me to open or save) or open the pdf on the current window, but same problem, don't know how to grab the pdf. So dead ends everywhere.

Thanks in advance.

```
library(RSelenium)
checkForServer()
startServer()
remDr<-remoteDriver$new()
url<-"http://www.dmo.gov.uk/ceLogon.aspx?page=about&rptCode=D10A"
remDr$open(silent = TRUE) #opens a browser
remDr$navigate(url)
doc <- htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])

table <- readHTMLTable(doc, header=NA, stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
```

Comment: Off-topic: Please mark past questions as solved, if an answer helped you.

Comment: @lukeA,yes, you helped me on one question and I have just accepted your answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not correct that IE is needed to get effective interaction with that page. Using Firefox or Chrome on a Mac the small printer icon above and to the left of the data columns offers to "Print this report" when moused-over and when clicked causes a file named "CrystalReportViewer1.pdf" to be downloaded. If one then uses the [cross-platform browser-plugin application named Tabula](http://tabula.technology/), you can extract the data in csv form. The top of the extracted data (on April 1, 2016) looks like:

```
Syndication ,Gilt Name ,Amount Sold ,Issue ,Issue ,Announcement ,Results 
Date ,"",(£ million ,Price (£) ,Yield ,Press Release ,Press Release
"","",nominal),"","","",""
23 Feb 2016 ,0 1/8% Index-linked Treasury Gilt 2065 ," 2,750.0 ", 163.73 ,-0.8905% ,Announcement ,Results
01 Dec 2015 ,0 1/8% Index-linked Treasury Gilt 2046 ," 3,250.0 ", 129.74 ,-0.7475% ,Announcement ,Results
20 Oct 2015 ,2½% Treasury Gilt 2065 ," 4,750.0 ", 98.40 , 2.5570% ,Announcement ,Results
22 Sep 2015 ,0 1/8% Index-linked Treasury Gilt 2068 ," 2,500.0 ", 166.00 ,-0.8655% ,Announcement ,Results
21 Jul 2015 ,3½% Treasury Gilt 2068 ," 4,000.0 ", 121.31 , 2.7360% ,Announcement ,Results
```

Instead of trying to extract pdf from that page (which is not in pdf form as far as I can determine) you should instead use RSelenium to download the pdf file to a local drive and process it from there.

This is the button ID:

```
{'id':'CrystalReportViewer1_toptoolbar_print'}
```

There are demos in the RSelenium help pages. One is entitled: selDownloadZip.R. It shows how to execute a "click" on a "page Element":

```
webElem <- remDr$findElement("id", "CrystalReportViewer1_toptoolbar_print")
webElem$clickElement()
```

Then looking at the "element Inspector" in Firefox's ViewSource panel I see the name of the button ("id", "theBttnbobjid_1459536946505_dialog_submitBtn"), so a further click is needed. However that number changes with each page access, so use  `webElem <- remDr$findElement("link text", "Export")`

```
 webElem <- remDr$findElement("link text", "Export")
 webElem$clickElement()
```

It would be a good idea to review the webElement-class help page.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. When I said only IE works, I meant if you click on the buttons at the very bottom in other browsers, it pops up error msg e.g. chrome says "Multiple distinct Content-Disposition headers received. This is disallowed to protect against HTTP response splitting attacks." I don't have a Mac, so I don't know if your solution would still work?

Comment: Exactly. I got that response from both Chrome and Firefox on my Mac when using the buttons at the bottom of the page. Which was why I tried using the Print-to-pdf mechanism at the top of the page.

Comment: I see what you mean now, my brain is just not working after hours of straggling with this website...So you are saying that I need Tabula to call that printer icon in R? I guess still confused here....All I am trying to say is I can use R to access the buttons at the very bottom, but even though I ask R to click on them, it won't work because this error on firefox. Is there a way in R to call that small printer button? I don't know how to even find it in source code...

Comment: No. RSelenium should let you call for the download. I offered Tabula as a mechanism for extracting data from a local pdf file.

Comment: I see, I should really change my question to "How to call that small printer icon in RSelenium.“ Because this is my 2nd R code and getting this far is already a lot of headache....no idea how to call it...

Comment: thanks, I read from other posts on how to click a button, but can you also teach me how to click on the popup window after I click the printer icon? That's the part where I am stuck at...In this case, I need to click on this Export thingy...And can't find any useful information online...

Comment: OK. Sorted it out on my Mac. See above.  Name of the page element should be the same on any browser.

Comment: really? Let me try yours, because I did it this way but it didn't work on the second click.

Comment: searchID<-'//*[@id="CrystalReportViewer1_toptoolbar_print"]'
webElem<-remDr$findElement(value = searchID)
webElem$clickElement()

searchID<-'//*[@id="theBttnbobjid_1459536953250_dialog_submitBtn"]'
webElem<-remDr$findElement(value =searchID)
webElem$clickElement()

Comment: strange, your code (Which I think is the same logic as mine above) didn't work on mine,  Error:   Summary: UnknownError
   Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
   class: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException

Comment: The dialog needs to be visible. I suspect it was not visible at the time of executing hte code.

Comment: You don't need to give me a checkmark yet, although I do think all this work at the very least deserves an upvote.

Comment: of course, I should have done it earlier, thanks very much for your help

Comment: I know why it didn't work, it is not a static id of the export button, it changes every time. So if I hard code it, it won't work.

Comment: Maybe we can identify a stable unique attribute. The funny number at the end of that names did seem kind of weird.

Comment: I agree. I am trying to find a way to put a wildcard in between "theBttnbobjid_" and "_dialog_submitBtn"

Comment: Try this:  `webElem <- remDr$findElement("link text", "Export")` then "click".